# Ethernet not working on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, networking, ethernet

I just downloaded a fresh Raspbian image and I can't get the ethernet to work with it. The strange thing is that it works without problem on my OpenElec SD card.

I tried many things with the `/etc/network/interfaces` file and I even tried to plug a wifi usb dongle without success.

iwconfig:

```
lo    no wireless extensions
eth0  no wireless extension
```

ifconfig eth0:

```
eth0    Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
        UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
        RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
        RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

with the /etc/network/interfaces :

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I tried to switch the ethernet cable without success (even if both work with OpenElec).

It starts to turn me crazy and I think I will try with an Arch or a Pidora soon if I don't find a solution. But I'm more confortable with debian so that makes me a little bit sad :(

EDIT: Okay, network stopped working on my OpenElec install too. So I got a little angry, threw the Pi on the sofa and the network LEDs started blinking again. Everything works now. Conclusion of the story : if you don't understand why things don't work, try to break them, that'll fix them.

Comment: try removing the line `allow-hotplug eth0` and line `auto eth0`. I don't think they are needed.

Comment: Doesn't change anything :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same problem some time ago.

Try:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
address 10.10.10.181 # Replace with your address
netmask 255.255.255.0 # Replace with your netmask
network 10.10.10.0 # Not really needed... If you want, set your network address
gateway 10.10.10.1 # Your gateway
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

iface default inet dhcp
```

That is my actual configuration.

If that works, it is likely that your Pi doesn't find a valid DHCP server in the network he is connected to.

Let me know if that helped :)

Comment: Welcome to the Pi exchange. Thanks for posting an answer but may I suggest you possibly describe how to work out if there is a DHCP or not as it would compliment the question and your answer. PS - You don't need to sign your answers - It is already signed with your name on the bottom.